# Is there a any benefit at all of using DB Project in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Our DBA recently introduce the whole idea of DB Project for maintaining sql (DDL and DML) check in part however I feel like it's of no benefit at all. Is anyone knows any benefit of using DB project ? I would like to know real benefit.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your DBA what his reasoning is?  "Hey, I was wondering, what benefits can we expect to see from this DB project?"

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "DB project"? If that refers to storing all schema migration scripts in git or svn and introduce a tool like Liquibase or Flyway, then your DBA is absolutely correct.

Comment: Certainly there is usefulness for many things - else, those things would not have been created. However, usefulness must be defined within a particular context. Can you add clarifying details to supply that context and what problem you have that you might be trying to solve?

Comment: It's hard to get real reason from my DBA, only response I got so far is, this how we need to do it going forward.

Comment: I understand however so far I don't see any use except now its takes forever to check in simple DDL. Also Earlier I used to leave Print statement in all DDL/DML script so that if any thing goes wrong doing production deployment I would know which exactly script is failing, with new implementation I lost that ability because now I am not suppose to include any print statement in my script.

Comment: @RahulLore Developers should NOT have access to a production system. Your organization has some significant risk issues. Perhaps your dba is trying to introduce some real management practices into the development and administration processes. However, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

> Is anyone knows any benefit of using DB project ?

1) It tracks the change history of your database schema, and stores your schema in a version control system.

2) It integrates with your DevOps workflow, and enables you to track what version of your schema is deployed in what environment.

3) Manages the creation of DDL change scripts for upgrading a target environment to a specific version of the schema.

4) Prevents Schema Drift in environments by detecting and fixing changes made directly in environments.

An easy way to get started with database projects is to continue with your connected database development workflow, and use the Schema Compare tool to update your Database Project and check it in to source control.

Comment: Thanks that was really useful. Earlier I used to do same thing using single multiple line sql file which I used to check-in with specific version of product. Is dackpack is same thing ?

Comment: A dacpac specifies what the database _should_ look like, and then SqlPackage.exe will compare the dacpac to the target environment and generate a change script.  A plain SQL script is fine for views and stored procedures, which can simply be replaced, but for tables and other objects you can't just drop them and replace them with the most current definition.